# violin plot with categorization using two different columns of data for "one violin"

Tags: python, violin-plot

trying to visualize the distributions of the data stored in a dataframe.
I have 1000 rows, each of them has next columns:

```
sample_id | chi_2_n_est | chi_2_n_theo 
---------------------------------------
1         | 1.01        | 1.001 
1         | 1.03        |1.012 
... 
2         | 1.11        | 1.04
3         | 1.21        | 1.03
...
```

I want to display violin plots for the data stored in columns  chi_2_n_est and chi_2_n_theo, but splitter - to compare the distributions for each sample_id in the dataframe.

Something similar to:

[image]

Where blue will be the distribution for chi_2_n_est, and orange for chi_2_n_theo for each sample_id...

Comment: I think you’re better off pivoting your data , so that your chi_2 columns become a a single column/value pair. I.e, 1 column that identifies the value as either est or theo, and the 1 column for the correspond value. Then you can use the base seaborn package to do the above visualization. Pandas should have a pivot feature you can use. Do you need a sample?

Comment: yes, a sample - would be perfect. Please provide if you can.

Comment: Maybe I wrote little unclearly. I will clarify: i want to obtain sample_id by x-axis (category) and the violin plots stacked together for chi_2_n_est (left blue) and chi_2_n_theo (right orange) for this samlpe_id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have your data, but I created a random sample that will hopefully mimic yours. I also misspoke, this is the opposite of a pivot, your data is pivoted

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

# create dummy data
data = {
    'product_id': np.random.choice(2, 22, replace=True)+1,
    'chi_2_ne': np.random.uniform(0.1, 1.9, 22),
    'chi_2_theo': np.random.uniform(0.1, 1.9, 22)
}

# load into a dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)

# use melt to blend columns into rows (opposite of pivot, actually)
pdf = df.melt(id_vars=['product_id'], value_vars=['chi_2_ne', 'chi_2_theo'], var_name='measure', value_name='value')

# use seaborn to create a violin plot where split=True
sns.violinplot(data=pdf, x="product_id", y="value", hue="measure", split=True)
```

To create [image: violin plot]

Hopefully this is what you are looking for, and similar enough to your raw data that it's useful. Notes on [pd.melt](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html#pandas.DataFrame.melt) and [sns.violinplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.violinplot.html) if you need it